# Creating an Android port of old PC games

Tags: android, platformer, pc, porting

I have seen some decent ports to Android of old PC games.

The graphics and game engines are the same, and all that seems to have been changed was the key mapping, and adding touch-screen events.

I want to play around with learning how to do this, but I have done a lot of searching online, and haven't been able to find a general overview of how to begin.

What would I to do, or at least, where can I learn how, to take an old, existing PC game, and port it to Android, only changing the key-mappings, and add touch-screen support?

From what I have seen, a native app is created to launch the game, and then from that point, you're just playing the original game.

And I'm not referring to playing games through emulators.  This is something that would be able to be downloaded from the Google App store.  And I would first get rights to do so, of course, unless it was, or has been released as, an open-source game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which game specifically? What engine does it run on? Is the source available? If the source isn't available then you're SOL unless you REALLY like decompiling.

Chances are good the code base is C or C++ (lets hope so). That means you have to compile with the Android NDK which isn't trivial. My experiences with it have been painful. You're right you have to refactor the game to use touch events which means a complete overhaul of the input system and designing a control scheme that works on a phone. You'll also need to re-write the window management system. Android uses an Activity system and you'll need to create an activity and a GL context from inside the NDK (which sucks) or you'll need to create the Activity in Java and call all the game logic through the JNI.

Lets also not forget that older games sometimes use assembler. x86 isn't compatible with ARM so you'll need to rewrite those sections in either ARM assembler or just C/C++ and let the compiler handle it.

It's not easy but at the end of the day you'll end up with (hopefully) an APK that you can install on your phone!

Speaking of assembler, compilers suck. Different platforms implement C/C++ slightly differently so there may be some parts of the code where the developers relied on assumed type sizes which can change from platform to platform. These problems might manifest when you try to run the game as random crashes which will require some serious debugging so watch out!

Lets not forget about drawing to the screen! Older games sometimes used "software rendering" where the program itself (rather than a GPU) would draw to the screen. This is big no-no nowadays so you'll need to refactor all that code to use OpenGLES. If the game uses hardware it will probably use an older fixed function version of DirectX which will need to be rewritten as modern GLES. Heck even if the game is using a modern OpenGL drawing system you'll still need to make sure all the shaders will work well on mobile.

A lot of problems can be alleviated by using SDL2's Android port. It should make it a bit easier to handle input and setup all the OpenGL goodies you want. Heck you could probably use the SDL surfacing system to draw instead of doing all the OpenGL yourself.

Here's a good article on writing native activities in Android: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html

Here's the SDL documentation for Android: https://wiki.libsdl.org/Android

For SDL you'll probably need to be using a *nix environment. Check out Cygwin or CMDER if you're on Windows (I like CMDER)

Good Luck! Don't forget to come back and ask more specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you for taking the time to provide so much detail.